# How to parse git diff of specific file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, git

I have an Android XML (string) file that is edited in a Ruby script. I would like to list and output the changes that were made then. I have tried it with Nokogiri and `nokogiri/diff`. But it does not have the desired result.

I also have the feeling that it has problems when a new line is added in the middle of it. All in all, I think it would be easiest if I could use `git diff`.

I've also found [ruby-git](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git) gem, but I still could not get it to work. Especially because I only need the diff of a specific file.

```
require 'git'

Git.configure do |config|
 #not sure if I actually need something?
end

g = Git.open(path_to_my_dir, :log => Logger.new(STDOUT))    
g.diff(path_to_file)
#or
g.diff().path(path_to_file)
```

Can Someone please help me out? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You thought in the right direction.

For this purpose use

```
require 'git'
g = Git.open('path/to/dir')
g.diff('your.file').patch #=> changes in your.file
```

For example we had empty files `git.rb` and `smth` in our git-repo.

Then we changed them and checked difference:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/git.rb b/git.rb
index e69de29..3ff224d 100644
--- a/git.rb
+++ b/git.rb
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+require 'git'
+g = Git.open(__dir__)
+puts g.diff('smth').patch
diff --git a/smth b/smth
index e69de29..7c5bd35 100644
--- a/smth
+++ b/smth
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+we want to know changes
```

As already guessed from modified `git.rb`, now we will see changes only in `smth`:

```
$ ruby git.rb
diff --git a/smth b/smth
index e69de29..7c5bd35 100644
--- a/smth
+++ b/smth
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+we want to know changes
```

In case there are no changes, you will get empty string `""`.

Comment: Hey i tryed this because it looks really simple. I tryed for example
`g = Git.open("User/me/android-project")` and then `g.diff("fobber/src/main/res/values/strings.xml").patch` but then i get an error like: ambiguous argument for my path: unknown commit or path does not exist
in the working directory :-( what am i doing wrong?

Comment: For example your file with this scipt is in `/home/user/smth` folder. It will search git-repo folder in `/home/user/smth/User/me/android-project`. That's because you have error

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working now. The problem was that in my script, the path to my .git folder was an absolute path and somehow, the path to my file was just starting somewhere in the folder. I am using an absolute Path now for both and it is working. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the McIlroy-Hunt longest common subsequence (LCS) algorithm directly instead of using derivates/wrappers of it.

See https://github.com/halostatue/diff-lcs

The diff will change if you compare changes of a vs. b as opposed to changes of b vs. a, but you can run it against an array **or** against a whole file of course.

The gem also has the classic diff tool formatting (used by diff or git) if you prefer that instead of using its direct output.